# Просмотр видео в обратную сторону

Tags: html, видео, javascript

Можно ли с помощью js запустить просмотр видео в теге <video> в обратную сторону?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
video.playbackRate = -1;
```

Свойство `playbackRate` описано [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_playbackrate.asp)

Comment: Благодарю!